# Calling Python script from PHP does not pan out

Tags: php, python

I am trying to extract major keywords from a text or sentence using python. I am using `python's RAKE module`. The following python code works well in the console. But, when I am trying to call the python script from PHP, the script does not parse any new text or sentence which I stored in a php variable, and instead outputs the old text/sentence even though I commented out it within the python script and replaces it with `sys.argv[1]` argument. In various ways, within PHP I tried to solve this problem using `PHP's exec and passthru commands` without any luck and so I finally decided to post my problem here.

PHP script

```
$var1 = 'The extra sleep will help your body wash out stress hormones.';

Technique(1)  
$output = exec("python rake_tutorial.py .$var1");

Technique(2)
$output = exec('python rake_tutorial.py ' .$var1, $result);

Technique(3)
$command = 'python rake_tutorial.py ' . $var1;
$output = passthru($command);

Technique(4) 
$output = exec("python rake_tutorial.py $var1", $result);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true);
```

Here is my Python code

```
__author__ = 'a_medelyan'

import rake
import operator
import sys

# EXAMPLE ONE - SIMPLE
stoppath = "SmartStoplist.txt"

# EXAMPLE TWO - BEHIND THE SCENES (from https://github.com/aneesha/RAKE/rake.py)

# 1. initialize RAKE by providing a path to a stopwords file
rake_object = rake.Rake(stoppath)

# text = "What you use depends on your baby's age and physical development."



# 1. Split text into sentences
sentenceList = rake.split_sentences(text)



# generate candidate keywords
stopwordpattern = rake.build_stop_word_regex(stoppath)
phraseList = rake.generate_candidate_keywords(sentenceList, stopwordpattern)
print "Phrases:", phraseList

# calculate individual word scores
wordscores = rake.calculate_word_scores(phraseList)

# generate candidate keyword scores
keywordcandidates = rake.generate_candidate_keyword_scores(phraseList, wordscores)
for candidate in keywordcandidates.keys():
    print "Candidate: ", candidate, ", score: ", keywordcandidates.get(candidate)

# sort candidates by score to determine top-scoring keywords
sortedKeywords = sorted(keywordcandidates.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
totalKeywords = len(sortedKeywords)

# for example, you could just take the top third as the final keywords
for keyword in sortedKeywords[0:(totalKeywords / 3)]:
    print "Keyword: ", keyword[0], ", score: ", keyword[1]

print rake_object.run(sys.argv[1])
sys.stdout.flush()
# print rake_object.run(text)
```

Comment: Are you required to use PHP?

Comment: Yes, I need the output from my python script to further process it--where I am using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your exec command is going wrong.Try the following command:

```
$var1 = 'The extra sleep will help your body wash out stress hormones.';
$output = exec("python rake.py '".$var1."'");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried to call the python script from the command line as well..It is giving the same old erroneous results. I am on windows 7 machine. Do I need to add anything in the beginning of my python script because of the windows?

Comment: can you update your question with the error stack trace?

Comment: There is no error at all. It just prints out the first $var1 instead of new/recent. Very strange.

Comment: Hi, problem solved. I see I have two scripts with the same name. I was calling the wrong script. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd mention that there is a RAKE implementation in php https://github.com/artofzen/RAKE-PHP